# Flex & OpenX Market: IMG URLs Incorrect Problem?

Tags: apache-flex, url, openx

I've got OpenX working on my Flex site. But, I'm having problems getting OpenX Market working. At the moment, I only get my OpenX dummy ad-- no OpenX Market ads are displayed.

So, I set an alert on the img tags and looped through the return. I'm trying to figure out whether the img tags that are referenced are correct.

The odd ones produce nothing. The even ones lead to my dummy ad.

http://www.mywebsite.com/openx/www/delivery/lg.php?bannerid=1&campaignid=1&zoneid=4&loc=http%3a%2f%2flocalhost%2fproject-debug%2fproject.html&cb=ff843a05b7

http://www.mywebsite.com/openx/www/delivery/avw.php?zoneid=4&cb=insert_random_number_here&n=a0ea89cb

http://www.mywebsite.com/openx/www/delivery/lg.php?bannerid=1&campaignid=1&zoneid=4&loc=http%3a%2f%2flocalhost%2fproject-debug%2fproject.html&cb=6e0356203b

http://www.mywebsite.com/openx/www/delivery/ai.php?filename=mybanner.png&contenttype=png

http://www.mywebsite.com/openx/www/delivery/lg.php?bannerid=1&campaignid=1&zoneid=4&loc=http%3a%2f%2flocalhost%2fproject-debug%2fproject.html&cb=6e0356203b

http://www.mywebsite.com/openx/www/delivery/ai.php?filename=mybanner.png&contenttype=png

http://www.mywebsite.com/openx/www/delivery/lg.php?bannerid=1&campaignid=1&zoneid=4&loc=http%3a%2f%2flocalhost%2fproject-debug%2fproject.html&cb=6e0356203b

http://www.mywebsite.com/openx/www/delivery/ai.php?filename=mybanner.png&contenttype=png

http://www.mywebsite.com/openx/www/delivery/lg.php?bannerid=1&campaignid=1&zoneid=4&loc=http%3a%2f%2flocalhost%2fproject-debug%2fproject.html&cb=6e0356203b&bannerid=-1

I've changed the name of my website for this example. Is there anything wrong with the odd URLs? Any ideas?

Thank you.

-Laxmidi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, image urls were correct. The problem was that no one had bid on an ad.